# Slow importing of CSV into Database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, csv, activerecord

I have a CSV file that I use to update data. It takes a really long time (about 10 mins) to update no more than 15.000 records.
This is the code I use:

```
task csv_updater_so: :environment do
    require 'csv'
    counter = 0
    time = Benchmark.realtime do
        save_folder = Rails.root.join('path_to_file')
        CSV.foreach(save_folder, encoding:'iso-8859-1:utf-8', col_sep: ';', :quote_char => "\x00", headers: true) do |row|
            #If the item is in the db I update its values
            if item = Item.find_by_internal_code(row[4]) 
                item.update(:price => row[9], :stock_b => row[10]) 
            end
            counter += 1
            print "updated items => #{counter}" + "\r"
        end
    end
end
```

I find it strange as to update the same model from an xml file it takes just a bunch of seconds. Am I doing something wrong?

I have also tried

```
task csv_updater_so: :environment do
    require 'csv'
    counter = 0
    time = Benchmark.realtime do
        save_folder = Rails.root.join('path_to_file')
        updateable_items = CSV.foreach(save_folder, encoding:'iso-8859-1:utf-8', col_sep: ';', :quote_char => "\x00", headers: true).map do |row|
            if item = Item.find_by_internal_code(row[4]) 
                item.update(:price => row[9], :stock_b => row[10]) 
            end
            counter += 1
            print "updated items => #{counter}" + "\r"
        end
        Item.import(updateable_items)
    end
end
```

Comment: What version of Ruby and Rails are you using? Old CSV libraries were indeed very slow. (I'm asking because `Item.find_by_internal_code` is an old style finder method.)

Comment: Ruby 2.3.3 and Rails 4.2.6
The time consuming part seems to be the update method, but even if I use "touch" there is no improvement.

Comment: So if you delete the update line the script runs in just a few seconds again?

Comment: Could it be that your database has grown significantly since you last measured your XML variant? Maybe a missing index?

Comment: Exactly, if I remove the update line it take about 10 secs

Comment: How fast does it run when you replace the ActiveRecord find and update calls with an SQL statement? I.e. replace the `if` block with `Item.connection.update "UPDATE items SET price = #{row[9]}, stock_b = #{row[10]} WHERE internal_code = '#{row[4]}'"`

Comment: Maybe a little faster,but no significant improvement

Comment: Also, the database is not that big, just about 20.000 records.

Comment: You haven't really told us much about your scenario. Are your lookup fields indexed? Are you letting the DBM reanalyze the indexes regularly? Why is your quote character `:quote_char => "\x00"`? You have binary zeros in the file as quotes? Show us an example of a single line of the CSV. What is the DBM?

Answer (score 1):

You problem is that the way you are doing you're basically doing a transaction on each insert, so it will be naturally slow.

So my recomendation, to avoid converting your CSV file to SQL `COPY` commands, would be to use [activerecord-import](https://github.com/zdennis/activerecord-import) gem.
It will take care of the associations for you and group the inserts by model. Also since it provides the support for databases in a separate gem you can take advantage of some nice features of your database, like Arrays in PostgreSQL.

Comment: The second  code  I posted  is  using  that gem, but  unless I am using  it the wrong  way, the timing  does  not fall  below  10 mins